# Xaringan text block with >

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, xaringan

I'm using R-Markdown to build an html presentation.

I am trying to figure out how to change options for the indented text blocks in Xaringan presentations using css, but I can't figure out what the environment is.

For example, if I am using the following R-markdown:

```
- Renewable and Non-Renewable Energy  
> [Renewable energy](https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/our-natural-resources/energy-sources-distribution/renewable-energy/about-renewable-energy/7295) is energy derived from natural processes that are replenished at a rate that is equal to or faster than the rate at which they are consumed, e.g. energy generated from solar, wind, geothermal, hydropower and ocean resources.  
- *Clean* vs *Dirty* Energy
```

I get the output that I want, but I'd like to change the options that affect the appearance of the indented text.

[image: output1]

The html source code that's generated comes out as:

```
- Renewable and Non-Renewable Energy  
&gt; [Renewable energy](https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/our-natural-resources/energy-sources-distribution/renewable-energy/about-renewable-energy/7295) is energy derived from natural processes that are replenished at a rate that is equal to or faster than the rate at which they are consumed, e.g. energy generated from solar, wind, geothermal, hydropower and ocean resources.  
- *Clean* vs *Dirty* Energy
```

How can I change the spacing around the indented text or, even better, create other similar environments that I can use in my slides?

Basic reproducible example of what I'm talking about:

````
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    nature:
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: "16:9"
editor: 
  mode: source
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown
- Renewable and Non-Renewable Energy  
> [Renewable energy](https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/our-natural-resources/energy-sources-distribution/renewable-energy/about-renewable-energy/7295) is energy derived from natural processes that are replenished at a rate that is equal to or faster than the rate at which they are consumed, e.g. energy generated from solar, wind, geothermal, hydropower and ocean resources.  
- *Clean* vs *Dirty* Energy
````

Comment: You will need to include more info about Jupyter - notebook or lab, and the packages being used before a relevant answer can be provided.

Comment: This isn't a Jupyter notebook, it's RMarkdown.

Comment: What is the IDE?  RStudio?  Everything you want to know about markup and lists is available at these 2 websites: https://cirosantilli.com/markdown-style-guide/#spaces-after-list-marker

https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/v0.26.2/doc/Rules.md#md033

Comment: Different elements in Markdown need to keep "social distance" with each other: https://yihui.org/en/2021/06/markdown-breath/ (i.e., you should insert a blank line before `>`)

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie. I was working on how to insert a citation below a block quote in a way that will look nice on a slide, so I think I've got it now. Will fix it and post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Content classes](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-format.html#content-classes) to assign classes to any elements on a slide, too. The syntax is `.className[content]`.

So to change the spacing around the indented text (i.e. text in `p` tag within `blockquote` tag), you can wrap it with a content class and define css property for this class and we can use this class `space` for other indented text too.

````
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    nature:
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: "16:9"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.space blockquote {
  margin: 2em 1em;
  padding-top: 0.5px;
  padding-bottom: 0.5px;
}

.space blockquote p {
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

## R Markdown

- Renewable and Non-Renewable Energy
.space[
> [Renewable energy](https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/our-natural-resources/energy-sources-distribution/renewable-energy/about-renewable-energy/7295) is energy derived from natural processes that are replenished at a rate that is equal to or faster than the rate at which they are consumed, e.g. energy generated from solar, wind, geothermal, hydropower and ocean resources.  
]

- *Clean* vs *Dirty* Energy  
.space[
> Clean fuel refers to these categories of fuels: kerosene, Liquefied Petroleum Gas (LPG), electricity. In contrast, dirty fuels refer to fuels that are in their solid-state that emit a lot of toxic substances and smoke.
]
````

---

[image: spaced indented text]

---

And to assign a class for a whole slide, there's a [`class`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-format.html#slides-and-properties) slide property.

Comment: Thanks! This is EXACTLY what I needed, so thanks for posting it. I hadn't been able to figure out that the ">" in R-Markdown was calling a blockquote, or how to change the properties.  I've now got it figured out!

Comment: And by  the way, you can use "inspect elements" to figure out the underlying html tags that xaringan (or rmarkdown) using.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.

The answers to my (poorly posed) question(s) was/were:

1. The ">" in R-Markdown triggers the blockquote class, so you can change appearance/ properties for that using CSS.
2. Use CSS to create a new / incremental style with similar properties.

In my case, I was looking to create a small area for citations under blockquotes, so I've accomplished that with:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
blockquote {
  border-left: .2px solid #275d38;
  margin: -5px 80px -5px 20px;
  padding-top: -0.5px;
  padding-bottom: -0.5px;
  line-height: 1.35em;
}

.cite {
  margin: -20px 80px -25px 80px; 
  padding-top: -0.5px;
  padding-bottom: -0.5px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```
````

which both changes the blockquote parameters and creates a new style for the citation under the quote, so it looks like this:

[image: sample slide]

Thanks to all for the answers and comments.